# android error while Parse string to double

Tags: android

```
enter code here

 06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yaraby.y/yaraby.y.ghost}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
  06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
 06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
 06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at yaraby.y.ghost.onCreate(ghost.java:89)
  06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
  06-27 00:34:04.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13633):     ... 11 more
```

Line 89 is

```
enter code here
  Double p1=    Double.parseDouble(x);
```

what i'm receving from server is String and i want it to be double and its already a double number but recive as a string

```
enter code here
 String x=inFromServer.readLine();
         String y=inFromServer.readLine();


            x=x.trim();
   Double p1=   Double.parseDouble(x);
                    y=y.trim();
        Double p2=   Double.parseDouble(y);
```

Comment: I was being [facetious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/facetious). You've got a number of `enter code here` texts still in your question. :)

Comment: Why do you keep creating throwaway accounts for posting to stackoverflow?   Searching for your app name yeilds and extensive list of throwaway accounts, unifying yourself to 1 may help people better answer your questions by providing more context from your past questions.

Comment: Well Eric this is my First Question on StackoverFlow !!! and Rather than blaming not real things cant u just try to help !

Comment: Really?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yaraby.y

Answer (score 2):

Does the string includes "." (like 123.45) or "," (like 123,45)?

You should replace it according to your locale settings. Try catch block also will work.

Comment: @ onuray sahin waht can i do ?

Comment: You can try something like this:
String numberStr = "123.45";
double numberDouble;
try {
     numberDouble = Double.parseDouble(numberStr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     numberStr = numberStr.replace(".", ",");
     numberDouble = Double.parseDouble(numberStr);
}

Comment: Incredible. Thank you very much @Onuray Sahin. This is what I was looking for during the day. I have totally forgotten about this fact that depending to locale some phones could have . and some , as a delimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Print you `String` x on console, also be sure to use the right decimal separator for your locale. Is it . or , ?

Test it in a small program.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: the String appear on the Map i toast it its appear as '31.25986114'

Comment: try to parse x.replace( '.', ',' );

Comment: Double p1= Double.parseDouble(  x.replace( '.', ',' )); like this ?? it give an error also and force close

Comment: do you have simple quotes in your string or you added them manually just for us ?

Comment: Also, try to print a double in console to figure out what your decimal separator is.

Comment: 31.25986114 this is the string

Comment: can you parse an other string like 1.2 ? If so, double check, you don't parse the right String.

Comment: yesss it can be done !! then what can i do i'm parsing the infromserver its a string contains of digits like 29.9837234

Answer (score 0):

`Double.valueOf(string)` returns a `Double`
`Double.parseDouble(string)` returns the primitive type.
Since you are assigning the result to a `Double`, it might be better to use
`Double.valueOf(string)`.
I can't get the code to break either way, but I'd say it's worth a shot.